# Getting "Status Code: 401; Unauthorized" when bootstraping Sitecore Commerce 9

Tags: upgrade, sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

I am trying to upgrade `Sitecore Commerce 9 Initial Release` to `Update 1`.
One of the steps is to do bootstrap in Postman.
When I do it, I am getting this exception:

> Status Code: 401; Unauthorized

Steps to reproduce:

1. I have already set "AntiForgeryEnabled" in config.json to false for Authoring and also for DevOps sites
2. In Postman, I have disabled "SSL certificate verification" in Settings
3. In Sitecore Collection in Postman, I have run GetToken command to get the authorization token
4. I run "Bootstrap Sitecore Commerce" under "1 Environment Bootstrap" section of "SitecoreCommerce_DevOps" collection. Habitat Environment is chosen

**How should I make my request for bootstrapping authorized?**

**What should I specify as SitecoreIdToken in Headers in Authorization key?**

[image]

Comment: Do you have any information in your Commerce Authoring logs, when executing boostrap command? There may be an issue related to Postman (it is not saving token to global variables if the variable is not yet created). So your second request (bootstrap) doesn't contain this token. Another possible issue is your custom domain names and incorrect configuration for IdentityServer. In this case, you will find more info in logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you trigger `GetToken` command you should get `SitecoreIdToken` set to your global variables. This is done on 'Tests' tab via the following command

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("SitecoreIdToken", "Bearer " + jsonData.access_token);
```

You can check your variables by clicking 'Eye' icon next to environment.
[image]

If the `GetToken` response is not saved to Global Variable, then you may need to create it with empty or dummy value and it will be automatically updated on your next `GetToken` call.

[image]

So you don't need to copy the token for each Postman script.

Comment: Even better solution than my quick fix in another answer. Thanks for describing further my last statement :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found quick fix for my question.

1)
You need to open "Collections" pane in Postman and open "Authentication" collection. Expand "Sitecore" section and click "GetToken". Click on blue "Send" button to get authorization token.

2)
Copy the token to notepad and add "Bearer " before it.
Something like this:
[image]

3)
In "Collections" pane, open "SitecoreCommerce_DevOps" collection. Expand "1 Environment Bootstrap" section and click "Bootstrap Sitecore Commerce".

Open "Headers" and put text generated in step 2 into Value column of "Authorization" key.

4)
Everything will now work out :)

[image]

Best solution would be to create global variable "SitecoreIdToken" in Postman and set it with text generated in step 2. With this approach "SitecoreIdToken" will be always applied for any request...

Comment: any idea why i get this same error while installing sitecore commerce.BootStrapping Commerce Services: https://localhost:5005/commerceops/Bootstrap() Bearer
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.1.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:253 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default

Comment: when i see in the logs i see the error "ERROR CtxMsg.Error.EntityNotFound: Text=Core.block.LoadEnvironment.EnvironmentCouldNotBeFound: Environment=HabitatShops"